# Vim Clojure Cider Fireplace connect requires specifying port

Tags: vim, clojure

I set up Vim + Cider + Fireplace for Clojure. As per [cider-nrepl docs](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider-nrepl) I added:

```
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.2"]]}}
```

to my `~/.lein/profiles.clj`. I did:

```
lein new app myapp
cd myapp
lein repl
```

All looks OK. I see However, when I do `:Connect`, it connects only if I specify a port. Is there a way for it to auto-detect the REPL port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Normally, when you start `lein repl`, leiningen creates a file called `.nrepl-port` in the root of your project directory, the contents of which should simply be the open port as an integer. You can manually create this file as well and fill it in, but be aware that Leiningen will overwrite this file with whatever port the nREPL server is listening on when you run `lein repl`.

Comment: Thanks Venantius - I already have this file with a valid port there, but when I do `:Connect`, I am still being asked for protocol (default nrepl) / host (default localhost) / port (default is empty).

Comment: Is the file you're editing within the expected source/test path for the leiningen project? If you're editing a file in a different part of the file system (one in which the `.nrepl-port` file can't be found by walking the root directory path), then Fireplace won't know where to connect.

Comment: Oh! One other thing - are you sure you're not already connected by default? I believe that when you do `:Connect` it'll always ask for all of {protocol, host, port}, but if Fireplace can find the `.nrepl-port` file it'll connect automatically when it opens the buffer.

Comment: OK, so basically `:Connect` is mostly useless in the "regular" flow where you don't connect to remote repls or such. Doing `:Eval` will 1) use the repl detected on startup 2) detect it even after `lein repl` is started afterwards. The [docs](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace) right now are a bit misleading then (` it connects automatically based on .nrepl-port, otherwise it's just a :Connect away`), at leas the second part. I think this violates the principle of least surprise here :) If it's "a :Connect away", then I'd probably type that :) Thanks for pointing that out Venantius!!